# Unable to install driver for serial/parallel port card on Suse Leap 15.2 with Kernel 5.3.18-lp152.84-default

Tags: drivers, opensuse, serial

I have an IOCREST SI-PEX50103 which is a PCI-Express Multi I/O Controller Card with 2 serial ports and 1 parallel port. It uses the vendor supplied AX99100 driver. I am running openSUSE Leap 15.2 with Kernel 5.3.18-lp152.84-default.

I have not been able to install the AX99100 driver on this Linux installation.
When running the make command from the installation source directory, I get the following error message:

CC [M]  /home/programming/iocrest/AX99100_LINUX_Driver_v1.0.0_Source/ax99100.o
/home/programming/iocrest/AX99100_LINUX_Driver_v1.0.0_Source/ax99100.c: In function ‘receive_chars_dma_done’:
/home/programming/iocrest/AX99100_LINUX_Driver_v1.0.0_Source/ax99100.c:1027:43: error: ‘ch’ undeclared (first use in this function)
if (uart_handle_sysrq_char(&up->port, ch))
^~
/home/programming/iocrest/AX99100_LINUX_Driver_v1.0.0_Source/ax99100.c:1027:43: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Before upgrading to Leap 15.2, I had openSUSE Leap 15.1 installed on this computer and I had no trouble installing the driver
and using this card. Right now, I also have CentOS Linux 7 installed on this computer and I can install the driver and use the
card on that installation.

I'm guessing there is some sort of a problem with the Kernel sources for the 5.3.18-lp152.84 kernel I am running.
Any ideas you might have for locating the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: That `ch` var is declared locally in `check_modem_status`, `u8 ch,lsr = *status;`.  It is not declared in the function `receive_chars_dma_done`, is not decalred globally either in the.c or .h files, and is not bounded by a kernel version check. Unless I am missing something, it's broken software that was never going to compile without making changes.

Comment: By broken software, do you mean the function receive_chars_dma_done or the driver file? This exact same driver file was installed on a previous SUSE Leap installation and on a current CentOS 7 installation.

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE -- Had to revert grub to Linux Header kernel 5.4.0-110-low-latency and edit typos in make & install driver

Okay so I finally got this to work on contacting the vendor (StarTech) support...

1. Vendor indicated that they tested on [Linux Kernel header 5.4.0-110](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/linux-headers-5.4.0-110-lowlatency) for Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

   ```bash
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install linux-headers-5.4.0-110 -y
   ```

   - update `/etc/default/grub` to boot to **5.4.0-110-low-latency** by default vs whatever the latest that ships with Ubuntu / SUSE
2. Download the driver from https://www.startech.com/en-us/cards-adapters/PEX1P2, fix typos in make file (vendor admitted this is a known issue). Really the main issue error for **ax99100.c** make install throws `undeclared ch`, this is resolvable by simply declaring in the script:

```c
    char ch;
    if (uart_handle_sysrq_char(&up->port, ch))
    ...
```

3. The driver build `make` command should now work, then on your `make install` command there is a missing line given the kernel directory doesn't exist. I added this with `mkdir -p ...` and make install works
4. Finally, to load the driver there is a command with io & io_high... run `sudo lspci -v` to get your hexadecimal port values assigned for the new parallel port hardware (in my case, *e010* & *e000*). You need to convert those hexadecimal to decimal to pass as arguments (online converter here: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html)

---

##### ORIGINAL

Interestingly I ran into the same exact error and was so glad to see another user recently experienced. Our setup

- Dell OptiPlex 9020
- Ubuntu 20.04LTS, kernel **5.4.13** (you can run `uname -r` to check)
- StarTech PCiE Parallel Port

On running their provided installation script from [here](https://www.startech.com/en-us/cards-adapters/PEX1P2), there are some errors...

Notably you need to change the `SUBDIR=$(PWD)` to `M=$(shell pwd)` to even run `sudo make`, but then you get the `ch undeclared` error... My thought was this is a typo / bad maintenance from the StarTech team that updates the driver Makefile.

I pinged StarTech's chat support sharing these details and they suggested the following for potential missing dependencies

> ##### Can you please give the following a shot and let me know if it works for you.
>
> - We’ve tested these steps when getting a similar error on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine running Kernel 5.4.0-113 and it seemed to work fine.
> - In the Makefile make sure $(PWD) is changed to $(shell pwd) in both spots (Sometimes needed depending on the customers configuration)
> - Then try:
>
>   ```bash
>   sudo apt-get install linux-source
>   sudo apt-get install build-essential
>   sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
>   sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev:i386
>   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.4.0-110:i386
>   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.4.0-110
>   ```
> - Try this command if the above does not work
>
>   ```bash
>   sudo ln -s /usr/include/asm-generic /usr/include/asm
>   ```
>
>   - Making the link to tell the compiler that asm-generic is also asm since that may be part of the problem
> - At the end, just in case:
>
> ```bash
>   sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Like I said, on our end this seemed to install the card without facing any errors. Let me know if you have any questions or if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem on Rocky Linux kernel 5.14. [discussion here](https://forums.rockylinux.org/t/we-cant-use-startech-pex2s953-serial-card-with-rocky-linux-9-2/10902)

The Startech driver compiled after adding "const" to one argument in ax99100_sp.c.

```
static void serial99100_set_termios(struct uart_port *port, struct ktermios *termios, const struct ktermios *old)
```

"modprobe" failed until we turned off Secure Boot in the BIOS.  Now dmesg shows ttyF0 and ttyF1.